# How to make a stack grow dynamically?

Tags: c++, class, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Here is a little program with my Stack class:

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
private:
    T *stackPtr; 
    int size; 
    T top; 
public:
    Stack(int = 10);
    ~Stack(); 
    bool push(const T  );
    bool pop(); 
    void printStack();
};

int main()
{
    Stack <int> myStack(5);


    cout << "Push 5 elements to stack: ";
    int ct = 0;
    while (ct++ != 5)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        myStack.push(temp);
    }

    myStack.printStack(); 

    cout << "\nErasing two elements:\n";

    myStack.pop(); 
    myStack.pop(); 
    myStack.printStack(); 

    return 0;
}


template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int s)
{
    size = s > 0 ? s: 10;   
    stackPtr = new T[size]; 
    top = -1; 
}


template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    delete [] stackPtr; 
}


template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::push(const T value)
{
    if (top == size - 1)
        return false; 

    top++;
    stackPtr[top] = value; 

    return true; 
}


template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (top == - 1)
        return false; 

    stackPtr[top] = 0; 
    top--;

    return true; 
}


template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::printStack()
{
    for (int ix = size -1; ix >= 0; ix--)
        cout << "|" << setw(4) << stackPtr[ix] << endl;
}
```

So, in order to use such a stack, I should declare it's size in the constructor before usage, just like `Stack<int> newstack(10)`, if I need 10 elements. So, what to do, if I don't know the final size of a stack? How to make it grow dynamically, just by pushing elements to it? I was searching for a solution, but still all my ideas come to counting elements and then declaring a stack to fit elements number.

Comment: Instead of array, use linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are aware that C++ has [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) built in, aren't you? For the rest of the answer, I'll assume that you have some reason not to use it (perhaps it's a learning exercise).

---

A very naïve way to achieve what you want would be:

1. On every addition of an element, allocate a new array of *size + 1* with `new[]`.
2. Copy all elements of the old array and the new element to the new array.
3. `delete[]` the old array.
4. Make `stackPtr` point to the new array.

All performance and exception-safety pitfalls of this solution aside, how could it possibly work if your element type `T` does not have a default constructor? It would not even compile. In fact, your class fails as it is for the following `T`:

```
struct CannotUseInThisStack
{
    CannotUseInThisStack(int) {} // no default constructor
};

Stack<CannotUseInThisStack> s; // error
```

The real solution is: Don't use `new[]` and `delete[]`. Implement your stack in terms of `std::vector` (or in terms of `std::deque`, which is exactly what `std::stack` does by default!). `std::vector` supports dynamical growing out of the box, in a much better way, without continuous reallocation on every addition of an element and without the requirement of being able to default-construct `T`.

Of course, this rightfully leads to the question of how `std::vector` can do all of this, then.

The answer is that `std::vector`, or rather its standard allocator, [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), is *not* implemented itself in terms of `new[]` and `delete[]` but in terms of placement new. Memory allocation and element construction are separated. See [`std::allocator:allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate). This solves the problem with missing default constructors. Raw memory is allocated first and the new element is then constructed in that raw memory location, using the copy constructor (in C++11, you also have perfect forwarding to construct the `T` in place, but that's getting a bit off-topic).

Using placement new also allows `std::vector`'s capacity to grow exponentially. The container does not need to reallocate memory every time you add an element; it allocates raw memory for more elements in advance (similar to what Christophe does in his answer). Reallocation only takes place when the current capacity is exceeded.

With `new[]` and `delete[]`, such an elaborate mechanism would be impossible.

---

Generally, if you want to understand serious container design, look at how your compiler implements all the **C++ standard containers**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that suggesting to use [`std::stack()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) wouldn't be the answer you expect ;-)

You simply have to allocate more space when you reach the limit:

```
template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::push(const T value)
{
    if (top == size - 1) {
        //return false; 
        size_t s = size + 10;       // for example increase by 10
        T *ps = new (nothrow) T[s]; // allocate new region
        if (ps==nullptr) 
            return false;           // out of memory
        for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++) 
            ps[i] = stackPtr[i];  
        delete[] stackPtr;  
        stackPtr = ps; 
        size = s;                  // stack is now bigger,  
    }                              // so continue as if there was no problem

    top++;
    stackPtr[top] = value; 

    return true; 
}
```

The question is, by how much to increase your stack.  You could use a constant approach as here, but better consider a member variable and initialise it in your constructor.

***Edit:*** I've used the new with `nothrow` to avoid throwing an exception in case of insufficient memory, because your signature foresees a return code on the success of the operation.

Comment: `new` will throw `std::bad_alloc`, not return `nullptr`. And you should mention that it's not exception-safe. `T`'s assignment operator could throw.

Comment: @ChristianHackl sorry; forgott the nothrow;  I'll correct

Comment: I still think that the exception-safety problem should be addressed, too, at least by mentioning it. There'll be a memory leak if `ps[i] = stackPtr[i];` throws.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make this using a linked-list. If you want to insert into the stack then you just put a node at the head of the linked list. To pop, you just remove it. Now you may think how to implement this kind of statements like Stack `S=new Stack(5);`.

You just keep a counter keeping this value. You can implement any check over this variable ( like stack overflow etc). You just make it dynamic like the C++ STL supports and it will be easy to work with it.

Comment: If you want poor performance (cache misses), a linked list is the way to go. Probably you don't want that when implementing a stack.

Comment: @JorenHeit Indeed the performance will not be good. But I just gave him the idea of dynamic grow or shrink. You can always use an array and increase it when 80% or 70% of it is filled, that is obviously a way to do and performance is better that case. I just gave a simple way to achieve dynamic grow.

Comment: Agreed. However, I don't think it is wise to offer non-good-practise solutions to novices. In case you didn't know: the rule of thumb is to "not use linked lists", hardly ever! It has been shown that, even if your problem presents itself as a linked list problem, a vector (or whatever other consecutive memory solution) almost always outperforms the linked list (e.g. `std::list`).

Comment: @JorenHeit.:  I agree. From next post onwards I will try to be more precise and accurate. Thanks